# Clean memory after getting an element from queue

Tags: c#, .net, database, multithreading, memory

Suppose we have the following situation:

We have 2-3 tables in database with a huge amount of data (let it be 50-100mln of records) and we want to add 2k of new records. But before adding them we need to check our db on duplicates. So if this 2k contains records which we have in our DB we should ignore them. But to find out whether new record is a duplicate or not we need info from both tables (for example we need to make left join).
The idea of solution is: one task or thread create a suitable data for comparison and pushes data into queue (by batches, not record by record), so our queue(or concurrentQueue) is a global variable. The second thread gets batch from queue and look it through. But there's a problem - memory is growing...

How can I clean memory after I've surfed through the batch?

P.S. If smb has another idea how to optimize this process - please describe it...

Comment: Any reason to not simply dump all 2k records into a temp table and filter with SQL on the server as needed?

Comment: I would do this in the SQL Server in a stored procedure.  If you need to create a temporary table use a view in the database.  The SQL server is better at managing memory than the c# application.

Comment: I think it would be longer... Maybe I'm mistaken. 
If you want to know details - I don't find exactly duplicates. I find similar records and depending on its similarity I do one or a few actions (in first case I wil update existing record, in second case create new, third - ignore). And also I don't have exactly 2 threads... I have one which creates batch for 10k and when I got it - I start new task. So I try to compare several batches at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

This is not the specific answer to the question you are asking, because what you are asking, doesn't really make sense to me.

if you are looking to update specific rows:

INSERT INTO tablename (UniqueKey,columnname1, columnname2, etc...)
VALUES (UniqueKeyValue,value1,value2, etc....) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE columnname1=value1, columnname2=value2, etc...

If not, simply ignore/remove the update statement.

This would be darn fast, considering, it would use the unique index of whatever field you want to be unique, and just do an insert or update. No need to validate in a separate table or anything.